# How to pick "Page= ?" valuse from href html tag using Selenium Webdriver and Java

Tags: java, javascript, html, selenium-webdriver

In below mentioned HTML code wana pick " page = ? " value from particular "href" tag  . so i can pick that value and use that particular value in my selenium webdriver script , so my loop will run till 53 page.

this " page = " value mention in "href" tag please tell me how to pick page = value

```
<li>

<a id="quotes_content_left_lb_LastPage" class="pagerlink" href="http://www.abcd.com/symbol/ctsh/institutional-holdings?page=53">last >></a>

</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = document.getElementById('quotes_content_left_lb_LastPage').href.split('=');
var value = arr[arr.length-1];

//value equals 53
```

Is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
WebElement lnk = driver.findElement(By.id("quotes_content_left_lb_LastPage"));
int loopCount = Integer.parseInt(lnk.getAttribute("href").split("page=")[1]);
```

Basically you can use getAttribute function of WebElement interface to get value of any attribute and after that, its pure java.

Comment: Happy to help...If it worked, plz mark it answered so that it would help others too... :)

Comment: Hi Vivek , Want ur help on one scenario , for example want to fetch Column name:  Owner Name | Shared Held | Date from data grid  website link http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/ctsh/institutional-holdings in date range say 01/01/2014 to 31/12/2014 or 01/01/2013to 31/12/2013 and want put it into excel sheet. please guide me on this